# Skipping 'file already exists' error in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

Doing an intersection and some files already exist.Is it possible to tackle this error specifically and not with try except in general?

```
try:
    for i in cur:
        Intersect_analysis (in_features, out_feature_class)
except arcpy.ExecuteError as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

> file already exists.

This may pass any execute error instead of just this with a file being already there.

OR

Since the above error stopped the whole program and now has to restart,
another plan would be to search in the `gdb` which feature layers aren't there and proceed to do the intersect only to the new ones that haven't been processed due to the program stop.

Comment: `if not arcpy.Exists(out_feature_class):`

Comment: I think @Tom has the answer but if the feature class exists but contains no features due to a previous failure it would still be skipped, you could include elif int(arcpy.GetCount_management(out_feature_class).getOutput(0)) == 0: arcpy.Delete_managment(out_feature_class) then arcpy.Intersect_analysis (in_features, out_feature_class) to be sure the empty feature class is because there are no intersecting features and not a failure in the geometry engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell arcpy to overwrite any outputs if you wish:

The following should do the trick:

```
   >>> from arcpy import env
   >>> env.overwriteOutput = True
```

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/setting-environments-at-the-python-window.htm

Comment: Yeah although this wouldn't cause error it would double the processing.